# JavaScript Beginner Question (Loops)

Tags: javascript

Today is my first day in JavaScript. The book (JavaScript Definitive Guide) has an excersice printing all the factorials.

This is what I did:

```
<html>
<b><head> Factorial - JavaScript - Ex1</head></b>
<body>
        <h2> Factorials List </h2>
<script>

        var fact = 1; 
        var num = 1;
        for(num <= 10; num++)
            {
                fact=fact*num;
                document.write(num + "! = " + fact + "<br>");

            }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a problem which I don't exactly know. I checked the book and the way that writer solved it was by initializing the variable num inside the loop FOR. I did that and it worked.
But what is the difference between that and mine?

Enlighten me Experts :)

Comment: Can you put the writers code in your question just for comparison?

Comment: Young Padawan, you must read Douglas Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts - and each page needs about twenty read-agains. http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. It was a mistake I made actually.   @karim79 yes this book is good too. But many people suggested me to start with JS By David.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)'s syntax must be

```
for (<initializer>; <condition>; <increment>) {
    <body>
}
```

While any of `<initializer>`, `<condition>` and `<increment>` can be omitted, none of the semicolons `;` can be removed. That means, your `for` loop must be written with an extra semicolon:

```
var num = 1;
for(; num <= 10; num++)
//  ^
```

Or just move the `var num = 1;` into the `for`, which is normally what people would do:

```
for (var num = 1; num <= 10; num ++) 
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't use FOR loop much not even in Java. This is really useful information. Okay but how about if I wanted to use While loop?

Comment: @Mohammad: `var num=1;while(num<=10){<body>;num++;}`. Actually the `for` loop is equivalent (if there's no `break`/`continue`) to a `while` loop in the form `<initializer>;while(<condition>){<body>;<increment>;}`

Comment: Thank you again. I really missed using {for loop}. I'm going to read about it and do some exercise for it in java first. much appreciated I also never started reading JS book the code was shown in the first chapter as an example on how client side looks like. But I started solving it :D